# Snackbar Style Notification only shows sometimes in Javascript / CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor

I have a "snackbar" notification that comes up from the bottom of my views when certain events happen.

It works most of the time, but sometimes it won't show.

I basically defined a hidden div, then make it visible with some animation when the javascript function is called.  I pass in text and a background color.  I'm using the code from W3Schools and modified it a bit.

I'm having a hard time figuring out why it won't show sometimes.

I have run it in the Chrome web-tools, and set a break point, as well as a console log.  I get both the console lo and the break point where it sets the class to "show", but still I don't see the notification on the screen.

I have the z-Index set to 10, 9 higher than any other view in my code, so no reason it would be behind anything.

I'm just looking for suggestions on other things to try.  Code below:

This is in Meteor, so there is a template being used for the notification.

```
<template name="snackbar">
    <div id="snackbar" class="snackbar shadow"></div>
</template>
```

Next is the CSS

```
/* Small notification bar displayed briefly on screen */

#snackbar {
    visibility: hidden;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-left: -125px;
    background-color: #93b7d6;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 16px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#snackbar.shadow {
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow: -5px 7px 8px #2f2f2f;
}

#snackbar.show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 4.5s;
    animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 4.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

And the javascript function when it's called:

```
// This is called to display the snackbar notification

showSnackbar = function() {
    console.log("Snackbar got Called!");
    var snackbarText = Session.get("snackbarText");
    var snackbarColor = Session.get("snackbarColor");
    var snackbarNotification = document.getElementById("snackbar")
    snackbarNotification.innerHTML = snackbarText;
    snackbarNotification.style.backgroundColor = snackbarColor;
    snackbarNotification.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function() {
        snackbarNotification.className = snackbarNotification.className.replace("show", "");
    }, 7000);
}
```

First I call it from this template and it shows:

```
<template name="entityManagement">
    <div id="manageEntities">
        <h3>Entity Management</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column column-40">
                {{> entityName}}
            </div>
            <div class="column column-40">
                {{> entityType}}
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                {{> addEntity}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Entity Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Entity Type
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Entity Networks
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product(s)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Actions
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    {{#each getCurrEntities}}
                        {{> entityTableInfo}}
                    {{/each}}
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The following template is hidden, and called when needed as a
    notificatioin to the user of some event outcome. -->
    {{> snackbar}}
    {{> entityNetworkForm}}
</template>
```

Here's the javascript from this template that will call it successfully:

```
Meteor.call('Entities.insert', entityName, entityType, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                Session.set("snackbarText", "Error Inserting New Entity!");
                Session.set("snackbarColor", "red");
                showSnackbar();
            } else {
                Session.set("entity_id", result);
                Session.set("snackbarText", "New Entity Successfully Added!");
                Session.set("snackbarColor", "green");
                showSnackbar();
                $("#entityName").val('');
                $("#entityType").val('');
                var entityNetworkModal = document.getElementById("entityNetworkForm");
                entityNetworkModal.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
```

If I call it from this template though...doesn't show up:

```
<template name="productManagement">
    <div id="manageProducts">
        <h3>Product Management</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                {{> productName}}
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                {{> productVersion}}
            </div>
            <div class="column column-20">
                <div id="addProductButton">
                    <br />
                    <button id="addProduct" class="button primary save"><i class="fa fa-plus-sign fa-fw myNav addProduct" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Add Product</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Version
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Added On
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Added By
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Actions
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    {{#each productNames}}
                        {{> productListTable}}
                    {{/each}}
                    </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The following template is hidden, and called when needed as a
    notificatioin to the user of some event outcome. -->
    {{> snackbar}}
</template>
```

Here's the javascript calling it:

```
'click #addProduct' (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var productName = $("#productName").val();
        var productVersion = $("#productVersion").val();

        var fullProductName = productName + "_" + productVersion;

        var countOfProductAndVersion = Products.find({ fullProductName: fullProductName }).count();

        if (countOfProductAndVersion > 0) {
            console.log("exists - you should see a snackbar....")
            // give an alert that the product name already exists
            Session.set("snackbarText", "Product Name Already Exists!");
            Session.set("snackbarColor", "red");
            showSnackbar();
        }
    },
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.